# React hooks exhaustive-deps rule also requires functions in useEffect array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

so I've got following effect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled) {
      setAnimatedValue(0);
    } else {
      setAnimatedValue(1);
    }
  }, [disabled]);
```

That simply animates button to its enabled or disabled state if `disabled` prop changes.

I also added following rule to my eslint config

```
  'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn',
```

Now I'm getting a warning that `setAnimatedValue` needs to be added to my `useEffect` array alongside `disabled` prop, but it is just a function that's neither a state nor a prop, so it shouldn't really go in there as far as I understand.

Is there a way to somehow make this rule only warn if I am missing `state` or `prop` value?

Comment: I guess there's nothing you can do besides ignoring the rule. Open an issue in the repo.

Comment: This is the most annoying thing about the rule for me - most of the time its helpful. But functions should not be included.

Answer (score 0):

If your `setAnimation` function does not rely on external state or props then it is safe to omit.

ie. if the only thing `setAnimation` needs to perform its effect is the 0/1 value passed to it - then its safe to omit.

Its likely a setter function so your safe.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies